# How to use eclipse IDE for fabric8 created java application/ RESTFul services?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, fabric8

I'm new to fabric8 and I would like to use eclipse IDE for fabric8 created java application/ RESTFul services. But unfortunately I can't find any tutorials, does anyone has a idea how to do it?
It would be great someone can provide me step by step tutorial for integrate eclipse IDE.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is explicitly off topic for this website. Also, writing a full step by step tutorial is out of scope for this website.

Answer (score 0):

A very generic question, but let's me take a shot ;)

Probably the easiest way is to start with one of the [Quickstart projects (archetypes)](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts), e.g. the [Camel REST SQL Quickstart](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts/karaf-camel-rest-sql). The usage within fabric8 is explained here: http://fabric8.io/guide/quickstarts/archetypes.html

And in case you're not familiar with the concept of an archetype in general, it's definitely worth having a look at: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html